# Is it possible to set a default value for a column when creating a table using ASP.net EF 5 code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating my database using EF 5 code first practices and cant figure out how to set default values (constraints) on a column.

If you look at my code below; I need the IsAdmin column to default to 0/false whenever a new user is added. Currently what I'm doing is creating the database using code first. Then opening up sql server management studio and going to design mode for the table and entering a default value (0) for the IsAdmin column.

Can this be done from the entity framework?

Heres what I got.

```
//Create CODE FIRST Database Tables.
public class MyDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
}

//Users Table in SQL Server
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Password { get; set; }      

    [Required]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can make IsAdmin default to 0 in code by setting it in the constructor. You can't leave it to the database to set during insert anyway.

Comment: A boolean is false by default. Since the column is not nullable, it will always be 0 in the database when you don't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply have to add

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Computed)]      
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

or in the mapping

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .Property(p => p.CreatedDate )
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
    }
```

Other then those data annotations there is no functionality implemented as far as I know, but you should be able to update the table manually... I found [this example here:](http://www.prescottnasser.com/post/2012/05/16/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Default-Column-Values.aspx)

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MyDatabaseInitializer());
}

public class MyDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbContext>
{
     protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
     {
        context.Database
             .ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("ALTER TABLE {0} ADD DEFAULT ({1}) FOR [{2}]", "Users", "getdate()", "CreatedDate"));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() method to solve my issue.